# How to remove element from array of json based on array?

Tags: arrays, json, frontend

idArray= [  'cb53f7a1-107c-44fd-9df6-adeddaa5d3f0',  '428a1951-7519-421b-90ea-704002eb31dc'] issues=[
{    description: 'Necessitatibus unde ',    severity: 'Minor',    status: 'Open',    createdDate: '1974-09-07',    resolvedDate: '2014-06-06',    id: '3d90afa1-bbbe-4640-bf91-38b27f72279a'  },
{    description: 'In quidem praesentiu',    severity: 'Critical',    status: 'Close',    createdDate: '2010-06-30',    resolvedDate: '2003-07-26',    id: 'cb53f7a1-107c-44fd-9df6-adeddaa5d3f0'  },
{    description: 'Error eum excepturi ',    severity: 'Minor',    status: 'Open',    createdDate: '1985-12-04',    resolvedDate: '2012-02-04',    id: 'a926ce55-79a3-4d38-923b-59b92cb2164a'  },
{    description: 'Laborum Vitae provi',    severity: 'Critical',    status: 'Inprogress',    createdDate: '2021-08-27',    resolvedDate: '2011-04-06',    id: '428a1951-7519-421b-90ea-704002eb31dc'  },
{    description: 'In amet obcaecati e',    severity: 'Minor',    status: 'Open',    createdDate: '2003-10-17',    resolvedDate: '1979-04-25',    id: 'dc137785-c283-4e54-a8c9-176e80d07b97'  }
]```

how to remove elements of issues based on idArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse JSON incase not and `filter()` method to get a new array filled with elements that pass a test provided by a function. Here's the code,

```js
const dArray = [
  "cb53f7a1-107c-44fd-9df6-adeddaa5d3f0",
  "428a1951-7519-421b-90ea-704002eb31dc",
];

const issues = [
  {
    description: "Necessitatibus unde ",
    severity: "Minor",
    status: "Open",
    createdDate: "1974-09-07",
    resolvedDate: "2014-06-06",
    id: "3d90afa1-bbbe-4640-bf91-38b27f72279a",
  },
  {
    description: "In quidem praesentiu",
    severity: "Critical",
    status: "Close",
    createdDate: "2010-06-30",
    resolvedDate: "2003-07-26",
    id: "cb53f7a1-107c-44fd-9df6-adeddaa5d3f0",
  },
  {
    description: "Error eum excepturi ",
    severity: "Minor",
    status: "Open",
    createdDate: "1985-12-04",
    resolvedDate: "2012-02-04",
    id: "a926ce55-79a3-4d38-923b-59b92cb2164a",
  },
  {
    description: "Laborum Vitae provi",
    severity: "Critical",
    status: "Inprogress",
    createdDate: "2021-08-27",
    resolvedDate: "2011-04-06",
    id: "428a1951-7519-421b-90ea-704002eb31dc",
  },
  {
    description: "In amet obcaecati e",
    severity: "Minor",
    status: "Open",
    createdDate: "2003-10-17",
    resolvedDate: "1979-04-25",
    id: "dc137785-c283-4e54-a8c9-176e80d07b97",
  },
];

const data_filter = issues.filter((element) => !dArray.includes(element.id));
console.log(data_filter);
```